# Jquery show/hide button not working on homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a little button show hide code for my homepage. If I put that code in internal pages it works fine but if I put it on homepage it doesn't work. If I put Jquery CDN in header so my revolution slider stops working.

Here's my homepage section where you can see the code:

```
http://www.mythstreet.com/#our-services
```

Here's my fiddle that is fine working:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/junaidkhawaja/ha6qp7w4/6/
```

Here's snippet of my code:
**HTML**

```
    <div id="1">
    My Content 1
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;">
    My Dynamic Content
</div>

<div id="static" style="display:none;">
    My Static Content
</div>
<button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
<hr />
<div id="3">
    My Content 1
</div>

<div id="4" style="display:none">
    My Dynamic Content
</div>

<div id="static2" style="display:none;">
    My Static Content
</div>
<button id="btnClick2">Click me!</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#btnClick').on('click',function(){
    if($('#1').css('display')!='none'){
    $('#2').html($('#static').html()).show().siblings('#1').hide();
    }else if($('#2').css('display')!='none'){
        $('#1').show().siblings('#2').hide();
    }
});
    $('#btnClick2').on('click',function(){
    if($('#3').css('display')!='none'){
    $('#4').html($('#static2').html()).show().siblings('#3').hide();
    }else if($('#4').css('display')!='none'){
        $('#3').show().siblings('#4').hide();
    }
});
    });
```

**Update: I found that after putting this code, my sliders is not working as well.**

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Comment: On your page you don't have the click handlers in a $(document).ready()

Comment: Probably has something to do with no conflict mode, and the order your loading scripts.

Comment: I added those handlers but not worked as well..

Comment: You have an error on LN 561:  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: Always take a look at your console (usually `F12`) you are currently receiving an error. `$(function` is not valid.

Comment: I don't know how to debug, that's why I am here..

Comment: Lol.. I debugged with you people help... It was the issue of $ sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, at the very first line you miss the $

**This one:**

```
$( document ).ready(function()
```

**Should be:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($)
```

Comment: Yeah, I look over that but can you tell me if I am right in putting that $ sign... ?

Comment: It's not necessary.  If $ is visible outside of the enclosure scope it will be visible inside.  How many times have you used:  var self = this so you can access inside.  I'd assume a lot.

Comment: Try something like this: `(function( $ ) { // code goes here
}( jQuery ));` to make sure jQuery is the library used

Comment: That works, but just remember that is not equivalent to $(document).ready(function(){}).  It's a self executing function that will run as soon as it's loaded, not necessarily when the dom is ready.

Comment: If you really suspect it's a conflict between jQuery and another lib, use jQuery(docuemnt.ready(function($){}).  In that syntax, you are sure to access the jQuery object AND to rename the first parm passed is referenced by $.  So sort of a combination of the other suggestions abvoe.

Comment: Yeah, I just put $ between function() and it worked.. I am totally newbie and your expert talks are over my head..

Comment: jQuery passes itself as the first parameter to it's ready function.  Which means function($) will now assign the local var $ = jQuery.  So knowing this, jQuery.ready(function($){}) makes sense, but $(document).ready(function($){}) is meaningless, because if you are actually able to reference jQuery by $(document), there's no need for the $ parm in your function.  Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Yeah, I put jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your site and playing around in console, I can see that $ isn't defined.

A quick fix for this would be changing your code to use `jQuery()` instead of `$(...)`

Note: Can't currently debug this further as you've fixed the code on your live site (hooray!)

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work.. I need to put $ between .ready(function()